# Title not showing properly using Tkinter GUIs in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, tk-toolkit

I am currently trying to learn doing simple GUIs with Python using the package Tkinter.

I wrote this program for a To Do List:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
import pickle

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title = ("To Do List")

def add_task():
    task = entry_task.get()
    if task not in ["", "Do nothing"]:
        listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)  
        entry_task.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    else:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="Doing nothing is not an option!.")

def delete_task():
    try:
        task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="You need to select a task to delete.")

def load_tasks():
    try:
        tasks = pickle.load(open("Aufgaben.txt", "rb"))  # reading binary
        listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        for task in tasks:
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
    except: tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title="Warning!", message="There is no saved file.")

def save_tasks():
    tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size()) 
    pickle.dump(tasks, open("Aufgaben.txt", "wb"))  # wb = write binary

frame_tasks = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame_tasks.pack()
listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(frame_tasks, height=10, width=50)
listbox_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame_tasks)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)

entry_task = tkinter.Entry(root, width=53)
entry_task.pack()

button_add_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Add Task", width=48, command=add_task)
button_add_task.pack()

button_delete_task = tkinter.Button(root, text="Delete Task", width=48, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()

button_load_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Load Tasks", width=48, command=load_tasks)
button_load_tasks.pack()

button_save_tasks = tkinter.Button(root, text="Save Tasks", width=48, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Everything works like I want it to work, except for the title.

Instead of the correct title, it just displays "tk" in the window bar.

Why does this problem occur?

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the title row to this.

```
root.title("To Do List")
```

The = sign is used to assign a value to something. In this case, you are calling the title function/method where you have to input the string of the title you intend to have as a parameter.

Comment: Ahh goddamn I really should've seen this myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`root.title()` is a method that requires a string as argument. It is not a attribute you access there.

Example:

```
root.title("To Do List")
```

instead of:

```
root.title = ("To Do List")
```